# PIL Draw.text and Lower Resolution

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, imaging

I have the following PIL code to print text in an image

```
import os, sys
import PIL
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw

img = Image.open("one.jpg")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)    
font = ImageFont.truetype("/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Times_New_Roman.ttf",27)
draw.text((100, 100), "test test test", font=font)    
img.save("out.jpg")
```

This works on one.jpg file. However on another test file called two.jpg, it doesn't print anything. From what I see, the only difference between two documents is the lower resolution on two.jpg. The file one.jpg is 200x200 dpi, two.jpg is 60x60 dpi.

How can I get draw.text to work in lower res?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a color for the text:

```
import os
import sys
import ImageFont
import Image
import ImageDraw

img = Image.open("two.jpg")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)    
font = ImageFont.truetype("/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Times_New_Roman.ttf",27)
draw.text((100, 100), "test test test", font=font, fill = 'blue')    
img.save("out.jpg")
```

Comment: That was it. I have no idea why color black kicked in by default for one doc, and not the other. But I guess always being explicit doesnt hurt, I will always specify the color from now on.

Comment: Yes, that is a mystery to me too.